# Find the minimum $n$ so that $\gamma_n$ is less than $10^{-4}$ from $\gamma$.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

> It is known that the sequence $\gamma_n = 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n}-\log(n)$ converges to $\gamma$ = 0.5772156649, wich is called Euler's constant. Find the minimum $n$ so that $\gamma_n$ is less than $10^{-4}$ from $\gamma$.

I am solving some exercises of numerical analysis but when I get to this I have no idea how to start. My first idea was to directly replace $ n $ but I have not made any progress. Could you give me any suggestions or what material to read in order to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: This question is incomplete: More knowledge about the sequence $\gamma_n$ is needed.  Are you thinking of $\gamma_n = -\ln n + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$?

Comment: Yes, this is the sequence. Sorry I did not realize that I did not write it

Comment: It is known that $$
\gamma  + \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{1}{{12n^2 }} < \gamma _n  < \gamma  + \frac{1}{{2n}} - \frac{1}{{12n^2 }} + \frac{1}{{120n^4 }}.
$$ You can use this to find the $n$ in question (it should be $n=5000$).

Answer (score 1):

As @cavok commented, if
$$\gamma_n = -\log(n) + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}=-\log(n)+H_n$$ and you want to find $n$ such that
$$|\gamma_n-\gamma| \leq \epsilon$$ use the asymptotics of harmonic numbers and you need to find $n$ such that
$$\frac{1}{2 n}-\frac{1}{12 n^2}+\frac{1}{120
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right) \leq \epsilon$$ For sure, you could take the first and second terms and solve the quadratic equation.

I suppose that $n=\frac 1{2 \epsilon}$ will be very close.

Let us try with $\epsilon=0.001$ and use $n=500$
$$\gamma_{500}=0.578215 \implies |\gamma_n-\gamma|=0.000999667$$

Comment: Thanks! But I have two questions. The first, I don't understand, what do you mean by taking the first two terms and solving the quadratic equation? And the second, How do you conclude that n = 500 is the minimum $n$?